How to make two alignments in the environment align?
I have a tex file
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{align}
\text{signal process:} \quad d X_t &= M (X_t) d t + d V_t , \\
\text{observation process:} \quad d Z_t &= h (X_t) d t + d W_t ,
\end{align}

\end{document}


The equality = is already aligned. Could you elaborate on how to align the colon :?

Just try with \text{signal process:} & &d X_t &= M (X_t) d t + d V_t , \\ \text{observation process:} & &d Z_t &= h (X_t) d t + d W_t ,

@MadyYuvi Yes, your command has my intended effect. The space caused by & & is a little big. Can we decrease this space?

The gap at every other & is the the remaining space divided by how many gaps there are (including the left and right edges).  So adding a bunch of &&s to  the left and right will make each individual gap smaller.

Sorry, but none of the proposed solutions is really good, Stephen's being the better.
I add three proposals in order of preference.
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\newcommand{\diff}{\mathop{}\!d} % for my proposals

\begin{document}

José Carlos Santos (colons aren't aligned)
\begin{alignat*}{3}
  &\text{signal process}&:\quad X_t&=M(X_t)dt+dV_t,\\
  &\text{observation process}&:\quad Z_t&=h (X_t)dt+dW_t,
\end{alignat*}

Zarko (there's a \verb|\\| too many)
\begin{align}
    \text{signal process:}       &   &   X_t & = M(X_t)dt + dV_t,   &\\ 
    \text{observation process:}  &   &   Z_t & = h(X_t)dt + dW_t,   &\\
\end{align}

Stephen
\begin{alignat*}{2}
  \text{signal process:}      & \quad & X_t & = M(X_t)dt+dV_t,\\
  \text{observation process:} &       & Z_t & = h (X_t)dt+dW_t,
\end{alignat*}

My first proposal
\begin{alignat*}{2}
  &\text{signal process:}      & \quad X_t & = M(X_t)\diff t+\diff V_t,\\
  &\text{observation process:} & \quad Z_t & = h (X_t)\diff t+\diff W_t,
\end{alignat*}

My second proposal
\begin{alignat*}{2}
  \text{signal process:}      & \quad & X_t & = M(X_t)\diff t+\diff V_t,\\
  \text{observation process:} &       & Z_t & = h (X_t)\diff t+\diff W_t,
\end{alignat*}

My third proposal
\begin{alignat*}{3}
  &\text{signal process}      &{:}&\quad & X_t & = M(X_t)\diff t+\diff V_t,\\
  &\text{observation process} &{:}&      & Z_t & = h (X_t)\diff t+\diff W_t,
\end{alignat*}

\end{document}



Thank you very much for your detailed answer.

@Akira Please, consider to use \diff.

I in fact use \newcommand{\diff}{\mathop{}\!\mathrm{d}}...

@Akira Oh, no! The dreaded upright ”d”!

@egreg, thank you for spotted  superfluous \ in the last equations line. I remove it now.

@egreg I have seen your comment...

Great answer (+1).

Use \begin{alignat}{2}...\end{alignat} or its star variant if you don't need equation numbers:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{alignat*}{2}
  \text{signal process:}      & \quad & X_t & = M(X_t)dt+dV_t,\\
  \text{observation process:} &       & Z_t & = h (X_t)dt+dW_t,
\end{alignat*}
\end{document}

Insert some spacing command (\quad here) between the first and the second & to control the distance of two parts.


I suppose that this is what you are after:
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{alignat*}{3}
  &\text{signal process\!}&&:\quad X_t&=M(X_t)dt+dV_t,\\
  &\text{observation process\!}&&:\quad Z_t&=h (X_t)dt+dW_t,
\end{alignat*}
\end{document}

The output will be:


@JoséCarlosSantos Now the second colon isn't next to the word.

With align:
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{align}
    \text{signal process:}       &   &   X_t & = M(X_t)dt + dV_t,   &\\ % observe two successive ampersands
    \text{observation process:}  &   &   Z_t & = h(X_t)dt + dW_t,   &
\end{align}

\end{document}



Through comment, OP said that, need to decrease the horizontal space after :

I didn't look to comments. This can be solved with one more ampersand at end of equations. It is corrected now. Now I see that actually I spell out your comment ...
